# Como extrair um arquivo SFX com 7zip em linha de comando?

Tags: windows, linha-de-comando

Gostaria de saber como extrair um arquivo SFX usando linha de comando, como exemplo eu tenho o arquivo [Baixar JDK 8, Self Extractor](http://www.java.net/download/jdk8u60/archive/b25/binaries/jdk-8u60-ea-bin-b25-windows-i586-21_jul_2015.exe), seu eu baixo este arquivo e o extraio usando o 7zip por interface gráfica, o arquivo é extraído sem problemas, mas se eu tento fazer o mesmo em linha de comando, usando:

```
7za x jdk-8u60-ea-bin-b25-windows-i586-21_jul_2015.exe
```

Ao invés de obter os arquivos, eu obtenho na verdade 3 arquivos binários:

```
jaureg
jucheck
jusched
```

Alguém sabe como extrair este SFX por linha de comando?

## editado

Tenho um software feito em node.js que serve como repositório em meu servidor, ele usa o módulo node-7z, que por sua vez no windows usa o 7za para descompactar arquivos, porém em testes eu notei que se eu tentar o mesmo processo em linha de comando usando o 7z ao invés do 7za nenhum erro acontece.

Comment: Eu votei pra fechar esta pergunta porque ela não me parece ser sobre programação. Apesar do exemplo usar um arquivo compactado do JDK, a pergunta é essencialmente sobre o uso do programa 7za. Certo? Talvez fosse mais apropriado perguntá-la no [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Olá, obrigado por sua ajuda, por favor leia o EDITADO. obrigado!

Comment: Opa, por nada. Mas então a dúvida (se eu entendi corretamente) é sobre o funcionamento da biblioteca/módulo `node-7z`, que aparentemente não funciona no Windows porque (conforme você descobriu por conta própria) usa o comando indicado que não extrai os arquivos corretamente (mesmo se feito manualmente, na linha de comando - e isso foi só um teste seu). É isso mesmo? Se for, eu diria pra você inverter a forma como coloca as informações. Comece explicando que a sua dificuldade é com o módulo (e não com o programa na linha de comando).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`7za` suporta apenas os formatos 7z, lzma, cab, zip, gzip, bzip2, Z e tar.

Uma [issue](https://github.com/quentinrossetti/node-7z/issues/8) já foi aberta no repositório oficial.

Comment: E acredito que tenha sido você que abriu